# How to detect more then 5 duplicate character in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm using this code to detect duplicate characters and I want to make it detect if there are more then 5 duplicate characters and it's only detecting 1, so aaa is undetected but aaaaa or aaaaaaaaaa is detected so 5 or more duplicated characters

```
var str = 'abcdefg';

var re = /:\s|,\s/;
var ar = str.split(re);
console.log( ar );

function hasDuplicates(str)
{
    return new Set(str).size !== str.length; 
}

if (hasDuplicates(str)) {
    console.log("Duplicate elements found.");
}
else {
    console.log("No Duplicates found.");
}
```

output:

```
[ 'abcdefg' ]
No Duplicates found.
```

```
[ 'hello' ]
Duplicate elements found.
```

Comment: Why do you split words? Why you match colon or comma in your regex? Why not semi-colon, question mark, exclamation mark, hyphen, and a few hundred other possibilities? What is the role of `arr` anyway, since you never use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with a backreference. It's as simple as `/(.)\1{4,}/.test(str)`

```js
function hasDuplicates (str) {
  return /(.)\1{4,}/.test(str);
}

console.log(
  hasDuplicates('asdfg'),
  hasDuplicates('asdfgaaaaaa'),
  hasDuplicates('bbbbb')
)
```

Update: 
If you want the number of repitions to be dynamic, you can create the regex dynamically using the `RegExp` constructor.

```js
function hasDuplicates (str, n = 5) {
  return new RegExp(`(.)\\1{${n-1},}`).test(str)
}

console.log(
  hasDuplicates('asdfg'),
  hasDuplicates('asdfgaaaaaa'),
  hasDuplicates('bbbbb', 7)
)
```

Update2: 
I just realized you're looking for a maximum repition. In order to do that you can use two regular expressions. One that checks for the minimum duplication count and the other one for the maximum.

```js
function hasDuplicates(str, min = 5, max = 10) {
  return new RegExp(`(.)\\1{${min-1},}`).test(str) && !new RegExp(`(.)\\1{${max},}`).test(str)
}

console.log(
  hasDuplicates('asdfg'),
  hasDuplicates('asdfgaaaaaa'),
  hasDuplicates('bbbbb', 7),
  hasDuplicates('bbbbbbbbbb', 5, 10),
  hasDuplicates('bbbbbbbbbbb', 5, 10),
)
```

Comment: is there a way I can add ```automod["config"].maxDupeChars``` to control the number from a json database?

Comment: @YuriDev Sure. Just add a second argument and construct the regex from it. I updated the answer with another example.

Comment: @YuriDev I just realized you're looking for a maximum of duplicate chars. See the second update for an implementation.